# MQTT broker for fault-tolerance

Tags: distributed, message-broker

Looking for a distributed MQTT broker that remains operational when one of its nodes fails for interdevice comunication using low-bandwith in time-sensitive scenarios. Its a low volume of messages and reliability in correct delivery is not of the essence.

I have tried EMQX before but is not really suitable for the purpose and when one node fails it simply hangs the execution and becomes unresponsive until the node gets back online. As far as I have seen HiveMQ and VerneMQ are not really suited for this purpose but correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the HiveMQ cluster documentation: https://docs.hivemq.com/hivemq/4.5/user-guide/cluster.html, I'd be surprised if it doesn't support your use case but please let us know. Feel free to hop over to https://community.hivemq.com as well - there's a bunch of knowledgeable folks including some from HiveMQ support who can assist you quickly. thanks!

Comment: Welcome, at the moment this looks like spam. You could make it less so by listing its features in your answer. Or even adding screenshots. Perhaps read thr help on how not to be a spammer.